# .die in javascript using jplayer.playlist.min.js created undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

Here's my problem. The following code below is from jplayer.playlist.min.js... about line 142 when you beautify the code.

```
**<more code above here>...**
_createItemHandlers: function() {
        var a = this;
        b(this.cssSelector.playlist + " a."
                + this.options.playlistOptions.itemClass)
                .die("click") **//ERROR HAPPENS HERE!!!!!!!!!!**
                .live("click", function() {
                    var c = b(this).parent().parent().index();
                    a.current !== c ? a.play(c) : b(a.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("play");
                    b(this).blur();
                    return!1
                });
        b(a.cssSelector.playlist + " a." + this.options.playlistOptions.freeItemClass).die("click").live("click", function() {
            b(this).parent().parent().find("." + a.options.playlistOptions.itemClass).click();
            b(this).blur();
            return!1
        });
        b(a.cssSelector.playlist + " a." + this.options.playlistOptions.removeItemClass).die("click").live("click",
                function() {
                    var c = b(this).parent().parent().index();
                    a.remove(c);
                    b(this).blur();
                    return!1
                })
    },... **<more code here>**
```

I'm running this to get a playlist run... here's a sample of the call:

This code is within a block that starts with:

```
$(window).load(function() {

new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
    {
        title: "Some title for the mp3",
        mp3: "../mp3/mymp3file.mp3"
    }
    ],
        {
            swfPath: "../libs/swfObject/",
            supplied: "mp3",
            wmode: "window",
            playlistOptions: {
                autoPlay: false
            }
        });
});
```

The codes ironically dies at the ".die" line here:  .die("click") "Above".

The error I get is:

Uncaught TypeError: 
    undefined is not a function jplayer.playlist.min.js:142
    jPlayerPlaylist._createItemHandlers jplayer.playlist.min.js:142
    jPlayerPlaylist jplayer.playlist.min.js:68
    (anonymous function) custom.js:64
    jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.11.1.js:4641
    elemData.handle jquery-1.11.1.js:4309

So, bottom line; whenever this call is issued: this._createItemHandlers(); The error occurs.

Many thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:

the jPlayer I downloaded was using deprecated .die and .live from an older version of JQuery.

Simply replace those with .on and .off and you're golden.  Now jPlayer works like a charm.

.die = http://api.jquery.com/die/

.live = http://api.jquery.com/live/

Hope this helps.

Cheers!